# change the div color when function called - jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

here is the list of products are printed using while loop

```
while($rr = $retval->fetch_object()) {
    $summery_return .= '<div class="w3-blue w3-card-4" style="font-size:18px;">';
    $summery_return .= '<span style="color:white;padding:2px;font-weight:bold" id="itmslct" data-proname='.$rr->product.'>'.$rr->product.'<span style="float:right;margin-right:19px;">'.$rr->qty.'</span>';
    $summery_return .='</span><hr style="margin:3px"></div>';
}
```

script

```
  $summery_return .='<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

            $("#itmslct").click(function() {
                var loc_proname = $(this).attr("data-proname");
                alert(loc_proname);
            $("."+loc_proname).css("background-color", "#f00"); 

             });

             });
     </script>';
 return $summery_return;
```

products in table

```
while($row = $result2->fetch_object()){           
    $icost=$row->quantity*$row->price;
    $progress_return .='<tr class='.$row->product.'>
          <td><b>'.$row->product.'</b></td>
         <td><b>'.$row->type.'</b></td>
         <td><b>'.$row->quantity.'</b></td>
         <td><b>'.$row->pack.'</b></td>
         <td><b>'.$row->topping.'</b></td>
         <td><b>'.$row->extra.'</b></td>
         <td><b>'.$row->comments.'</b></td>
         <td><button style="background-color:red;color:white">Done</button></td>
        </tr>';     
    $total=$total+$row->quantity*$row->price;                   
}
```

when i click on the product which is printed by first while loop then the background color of products in 2nd while loop should change.
There are multiple products in table with same name, all there background color need to be changed when i select the product on first while loop

i tried doing it but i don't see any results

Comment: id should be unique for each element use class attribute

Comment: for example if i select pizza then all the products named pizza and there background color need to be change

Comment: as JYoThI pointed out, you should use a class instead of id for `itmslct`, currently it should work but only on the first element (when duplicate ids, it works only on the first one found). By the way you should also use a prefix for your product name classes, in case it is a common word that could be used by something else

Comment: Can you show your whole client side code? Because the code piece which you've shared from that it seems may be your HTML DOM is not valid. By watching code piece it's difficult to say what's exactly is the issue.

Comment: attribute value should be enclosed by double or single quotes .

Answer (score 1):

I guess your code is not working because your HTML is not valid. In DOM; `id` should be unique. So to avoid duplicate ids; please modify PHP as well as corresponding JS code. Instead of `id="itmslct"` we will make it `class` as follows:

```
while($rr = $retval->fetch_object()) {
    $summery_return .= '<div class="w3-blue w3-card-4" style="font-size:18px;">';
    $summery_return .= '<span style="color:white;padding:2px;font-weight:bold" class="itmslct" data-proname='.$rr->product.'>'.$rr->product.'<span style="float:right;margin-right:19px;">'.$rr->qty.'</span>';
    $summery_return .='</span><hr style="margin:3px"></div>';
}
```

And associated JS would be:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".itmslct").click(function() {
        var loc_proname = $(this).attr("data-proname");
        alert(loc_proname);
        $("."+loc_proname).css("background-color", "#f00"); 
    });

});
```

Comment: when i am trying to alert the loc_proname it only shows half name of the product , after the space the remaining part is showing in the alert

Comment: then avoid using that value as an attribute value. Instead of that try to use product id or product number which will not have any spaces or any other special chars in it. If you have spaces in that text then you will have problem at setting it as a `class` of `tr` too.

Comment: can we give number for class?

Comment: sorry..not exactly number. But we can give class name like `class="prod_1002"` where `prod_` is fix part and `1002` is a dynamic part  coming via while loop

Comment: how to add prefix 'post' to this $("."+pid)

Comment: you can do it like `$(".post"+pid)`

Answer (score 0):

`id`s should be unique. You should use a class instead.

Also, it appears you're setting the background color of a `tr`.

Try styling the `td` cells instead.

Either target them with the selector

```
$("."+loc_proname + ' td')
```

or add the class to the `td` elements.

I would recommend the second option as styling specific element selectors doesn't scale well in your styles.

Comment: if i add class to the td then only the product part bg will be change but i need complete line to change

Comment: Add the class to all the `td` elements. I know, it's too much hassle, but try to get in the habit of always using classes and not elements and ids in your css selectors.